# how to select parent of a parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

the jstree looks something like this :

```
<ul>
    <li id ="head" ><a href="#">TITLE</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="body"><a href="#">BODY</a>
               <ul>
                  <li id="foot"><a href="#">FOOTER</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>

            </li>   
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is basically a tree with depth 3.

I just want to know if its possible to access the id "`head`" from the id " `foot`"

something like

```
             jQuery(#foot).parent().parent();
or       
             jQuery(#foot).parent().parent.attr("id");
```

or something similar

Answer (score 2):

IDs are supposed to be unique across your page, so you shouldn't have more than one element with the same ID, and hence you should be able to use just `$('#head')` to select it.

In your case, I suppose you want to use a class 'head', which could appear many times in your list.

The easiest way to achieve it would be using jQuery `closest()`. It finds the first parent matching given selector.

```
$('#foot1').closest('.head')
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: `finds the first parent matching given selector` - note that `closest()` starts looking at the current element, so it's not necessarily the first **parent**

Comment: If structured properly it would pan out though, that's the point.

Comment: @Ian, are you suggesting that closest can find itself?

Comment: @ZorleQ Yes. That's where it starts looking, then traverses up the DOM. For example, if you have `<div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>`, and use `$(".child").closest("div")`, it will return itself.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: @ZorleQ No problem. `.parents()`, on the other hand, starts traversing at the element's immediate parent. Another difference between `.parents()` and `.closest()` is that `.parents()` will return **all** ancestors that match the selector, while `.closest()` will return the **first** ancestor that matches the selector or **none** if no ancestors match. Most of the time `.closest()` is really what should be used, because `.parents()` will do too much work...but that's really up to the situation. I know some people will even use `.parents("selector").first()` but it still does too much internally

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method:

```
$('#foot').parents('#head');
```

Although, since the head has an ID, you could just look it up directly: `$('#head')`

Answer (score 0):

You cold write:

```
$('#' + $('#foot').parent().parent().parent().parent().prop('id')).do something with head
```

Make sure to read about the difference between .prop() & .attr()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are the only `<ul>` and `<li>` elements on the page.

```
 $('#foot').parents('li:last').attr('id');
```

Should give you the `id` which is `head`.

`parents()` function lists the parents of element from closest to farthest. So the last `li` element will be the one with id `head`.

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/52RGA/)